# Minimize autoinc id gaps during insert, how to?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working tables that slowly gather information, lets say tables A1, A2, A3.

Every now and then I need to copy the new information from tables A1,A2,A3 into tables B1,B2,B3. The tables are fairly large (~20000 rows).

The A1, A2, A3 tables use GUIDs while B1,B2,B3 tables have AUTO_INCREMENT ids.

Due to the size the inserts happen in bulks of 300.

If one of the inserts fails, then all the other tables must not have data inserted either, so I put all the queries into a transaction.

The solutions mentioned in this article seem to work: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/datawarehouse

Except that the article specifically mentions that this should not be done inside a transaction (something that I can't do as far as I'm aware)

> This INSERT..SELECT must not be done inside the transaction with the rest of the processing. Otherwise, you add to deadlock risks, leading to burned ids.

I also thought about using INSERT IGNORE and innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0 but I was unable to set innodb_autoinc_lock_mode with PDO, it just gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1238 Variable 'innodb_autoinc_lock_mode' is a read only variable'

Figuring out how to set the innodb_autoinc_lock_mode with PDO would fix this problem but I was unable to do it.

Just doing `INSERT IGNORE INTO B1 SELECT FROM A1` and ignoring the gaps also sounds tempting, but the tables are too large and the autoinc id quickly reaches the size limit

I have been struggling for several weeks with this, and I don't mind gaps as long as they don't increment this fast.
Does anyone have a suggestion for the best way to tackle this problem?

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with PDO. your database is called 'mysql'

Comment: That is actually very basic difference between database and API to access it. PDO don't store your autoincrement. whatever solution you are looking for, belongs to storage, not the way you access it

Comment: it shouldn't be solved at all. that's very basic thing about unique identifiers. They have to be unique. Gaps are all right. 4 billion is a big enough number to worry of

Comment: innodb_lock_mode again belongs to mysql, not PDO. mysql does handle innodb with all its locks. Worth to know.

Comment: @YourCommonSense don't you agree that inserting 100% of the data from one table to another table where 99% of the data is the same is just wrong? Wouldn't it make more sense to insert the 1%?

Comment: Just wanted to note that. Indeed your two-table design is flawed somewhere.

Comment: yes. this is called "quality control". Even if there is "cheap and dirty" "solution" which is actually not a solution at all, a proper approach have to be used.

Answer (score 2):

> but the tables are too large and the autoinc id quickly reaches the size limit

it is not.

If you insert a new record every second, limit will be reached in 70 years. And even this limit can be extended but a doubt there would be any need in this.

So, just don't mind gaps and insert usual way.

And - more on that - don't hassle with autoincrement ever. It is not something that has to be kept in order.

Comment: Is there any way that I could insert ignore with the traditional innodb lock mode=0 when working with PDO with the default lock mode remaining as =1 and not having to edit the mysql config file?